# How to get the value of a two dimensional array in Razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I have a jagged array as shown below, and the array is inside a c# code:

```
@{
    int[][] array = new int[2][4];
    // codes here that manipulates the values of the array.
}
```

Now I want to get/traverse to the values in the array.  But the code below just don't work.  When I run the program I got a run-time error "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < @array.Count(); i++){
    alert( '@array['i'].Length');
}
```

How to do that?

Thanks

Comment: `int[][] array = new int[2][4];` isn't actually valid C# - can you post the real code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like

```
foreach(var subArray in array)
{
   @:alert(subArray.Length);
}
```

but wont the length always be the same since it is statically declared?

Comment: the declaration shown is actually not valid C#, so it is impossible to say that it is "statically declared" - since the declaration *is not legal*

Comment: The above sample code is just an illustration, but the array to be generated has different length.

Comment: I think this one will be the better way of achieving the results, there is no point in knowing how many elements in the array if you only want to output the content. Just take out the `@` symbol, it is not needed half way through razor syntax.....

Comment: if `alert` is server-side, the `@` in `@subArray` is redundant; if it is client-side, it needs a leading `@:`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Updated accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Traversing multidimension array:

```
    int[,] a = new int[,]
    {
        {2, 4}
    };

    for (int i = 0; i <= a.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k <= a.GetUpperBound(1); k++)
        {
            // a[i, k]; 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I can see there is that the razor itself is a bit... odd; it is not clear whether the `alert` is intended to be cshtml or output, but the line does not look valid for either.

If `alert` is output, can you try:

```
// note this might need to be @for, depending on the line immediately before
for(var i = 0 ; i < array.Length; i++) {
    @:alert('@(array[i].Length)');
}
```

And if `alert` is intended as server-side:

```
// note this might need to be @for, depending on the line immediately before
for(var i = 0 ; i < array.Length; i++) {
    alert(array[i].Length);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you have the `@` symbol half way through the Razor syntax? the whole line needs to have a `@` symbol ....

Comment: Yeah, it just didn't make any sense, but what you've put is spot on